# Is this window installation (by a contractor) question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Before I ask on main, I'm checking here to see if this question is on-topic.

To be clear, I'm not asking the question here and looking for answers, I want to make sure this question is on-topic on main.

---

I am having vinyl impact windows replaced in my Florida home. Older building, block construction, stucco exterior. Where one of the new windows was installed, the existing sill was broken during the install. No problem, it's to be anticipated that some sills might break.

But because the sill is gone, I can see how the window was installed. There is nothing supporting the weight of the window frame, other than the front "flange" (not a nail fin, but a flange that can be cut to match the exterior opening of the window, and can be stuccoed/caulked to). I can see 2-3 inches of anchor screws and threads.

[image]

Shouldn't there be bucking supporting the bottom of the window frame? If the weight of the frame is only supported by a narrow flange, won't the window be prone to settling, causing gaps or cracks in the sides and top of the window frame where it meets the wall?

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe fasteners aren't meant to span gaps like that. They are meant to sandwich two surfaces close together. That's where the strength in the join comes in.

Finally, as I mentioned, this is in Florida, and the windows are impact-rated. I'm concerned that this doesn't satisfy Florida's impact or wind-load requirements. At the very least, I'd like to know if this is in accordance with the manufacturer's installation specs. I can't seem to locate PGT WinGuard installation specs online though.

Comment: "the sill is gone" - who ever left open the can of worms is at fault. It got broke putting in the screws but I'd assume they left it there, kinda doing something. Who ever pulled it out and did nothing afterwards should have done something.

Answer (score 3):

This looks on topic to me as long as you keep the question about how should the window be installed, and not contracting/legal advice. I would recommend compressing it to a single question: "has this window been installed correctly?" Turn the other questions into a list of concerns you have since a long list of questions can be flagged as "too broad" by the community. I'd also recommend additional photos that cover the entire window inside and outside, particularly showing any other ways the window was attached to the structure and weather sealed.

Comment: "has this window been installed correctly" Considering this is DIY.SE and this was done by a contractor, does reviewing contractors work fit the scope? I'm a bit hesitant this might grow into "Contractor Review".